# Cannot run Jupyter notebooks due to nest_asyncio.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using Python 3.9.9 via `pyenv` on a Mac with an Intel chip. I installed Jupyter using `pip install juypter`. When I run `which jupyter` I get the response `/Users/<username>/.pyenv/shims/jupyter`, so Jupyter has installed. However, when I run `jupyter notebook` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<username>/.pyenv/versions/3.9.9/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/<username>/.pyenv/versions/3.9.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 264, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/<username>/.pyenv/versions/3.9.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "/Users/<username>/.pyenv/versions/3.9.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 88, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/<username>/.pyenv/versions/3.9.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2141, in initialize
    self._init_asyncio_patch()
  File "/Users/<username>/.pyenv/versions/3.9.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2117, in _init_asyncio_patch
    nest_asyncio.apply()
  File "/Users/<username>/.pyenv/versions/3.9.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nest_asyncio.py", line 14, in apply
    raise ValueError('Can\'t patch loop of type %s' % type(loop))
ValueError: Can't patch loop of type <class 'NoneType'>
```

I have never seen this error before and my search for a solution has been fruitless. Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure that the virtual env is activated?

Comment: @GuintherKovalski I am using `pyenv`, not `venv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this error occurs for `nest-asyncio=1.5.2` ([issue](https://github.com/erdewit/nest_asyncio/issues/62)). Upgrading to `nest-asyncio=1.5.3` worked for me. You can run the following commands to uninstall the existing version and upgrade to `1.5.3`:

```
pip uninstall nest-asyncio
pip install nest-asyncio==1.5.3
```

Answer (score 0):

faced similar issues and solved using:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip 
pip3 install jupyter
```

maybe in your case you should use `pip3.9`

you can check the match of pip and python with

```
python --version
python -m pip --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Seens that it is a problem with jupyter and python 3.9:

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5912

One possible solution is:

1. - conda create -n py39 python=3.9
2. - pip3 install --upgrade pip
3. - pip3 install jupyter
4. - source activate py39
5. - Run jupyter-notebook

also, this issue contains mac os specific solution:

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5872